# how to expose node Crypto cipher.update() function in electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, electron

Iam creating an electron app and i want to use the node crypto library in the electron app. I have used electron contextBridge using preload.js to expose node crypto but how do i expose the cipher.update() function.

```js
// preload.js
const { contextBridge } = require('electron');
const nodeCrypto = require('crypto');

const { contextBridge } = require('electron');
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('nodeCrypto', {
    randomBytes: (size) => nodeCrypto.randomBytes(size),
    pbkdf2Sync: (...args) => nodeCrypto.scryptSync(...args),
    createCipheriv: (...args) => nodeCrypto.createCipheriv(...args),
    createDecipheriv: (...args) => nodeCrypto.createDecipheriv(...args)
});
```

Want to use cipher.update() like this

```js
function encrypt() {
    const salt = nodeCrypto.randomBytes(16);
    const key = nodeCrypto.scryptSync('password', 'salt', 64, { N: 1024 });
    const cipher = nodeCrypto.createCipheriv("aes-256-gcm", key, salt);
    const encryptedData = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(data), cipher.final()]);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't simply exposing the `encrypt()` function (i.e. providing `encrypt()` in `preload.js` and exposing it in the main world) work for you?

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner I thought only built-in node libraries could be exposed and not user defined functions. Will try it out.

Comment: I added an in-depth for completeness' sake. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can completely define your methods in your `preload.js` and expose them to the renderer processes to remove the hassle of exposing every needed method.

Thus, I propose to use the following code for your `preload.js`:

```js
const { contextBridge } = require('electron');
const nodeCrypto = require('crypto');

const encrypt = (data) => {
    const salt = nodeCrypto.randomBytes(16);
    const key = nodeCrypto.scryptSync('password', 'salt', 64, { N: 1024 });
    const cipher = nodeCrypto.createCipheriv("aes-256-gcm", key, salt);
    const encryptedData = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(data), cipher.final()]);
};

const { contextBridge } = require('electron');
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('customCrypto', {encrypt});
```

Please note that I renamed your namespace (`nodeCrypto` → `customCrypto`) to remove any possible confusion and added `data` as a paremeter to your `encrypt` function since it was missing from your original code and it would thus not have worked.

In your renderer process, you can call this function as follows:

```js
window.customCrypto.encrypt (/* data */);
```

In case you want to expose more functions (say, `decrypt` and `validate` for example) in the future, the `preload.js` context bridge definition would look like this:

```js
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('customCrypto', {encrypt, decrypt, validate});
```